# Android AsyncTask get() form another AsyncTask()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

**Background**

I have an AsyncTask (call it `uploadHeader`) that uploads some data to a server.

I have a second AsyncTask (`uploadDetail`) that  uploads some related data, which requires the initial data to have been uploaded: the header upload returns an id issued by the server, which is used to update the local detail records, before they're uploaded.

If at the time `uploadHeader` was initially called there were connectivity issues, the header info won't have been uploaded. 
So at the start of `uploadDetail.doInBackground()` I check the status of the local header record to see if it has already been successfully uploaded to the server, and if not, call an `uploadHeader.get()` to upload the header and wait to get the id back, before I upload the detail records.

**Problem**

It just seems to hang at the get() call. Debugging it, it seems to be creating a `FutureTask` and then looping somewhere inside that. It looks as if the second AsyncTask is being queued to run after the first one finishes, which it never does since it's waiting on the second.

I've read a number of other posts/articles on calling one AsyncTask from another, but they all seem to be focused on getting the two to run in parallel. I want this to block, until the other task finishes. It's also been mentioned that "execute(Params...) must be invoked on the UI thread.", none of the articles mention get(). Or is get() basically identical to execute() apart for waiting for the result?

As a workaround, I could put the http call to upload the header in a separate class and call that from both `uploadHeader` and `uploadDetail`, so `uploadDetail` wouldn't need to create an `uploadHeader` task. 
I'd just like to understand why it's not working as it is.

Comment: If one AsyncTask has to wait for the other... why not putting both uploads in one single AsyncTask???

Answer (score 0):

`get()` will block your execution until the second `AsyncTask` returns a value, don't do this if your first `AsyncTask` is doing some work that repercutes on the user interface of even in the workflow you've designed.

I'd definitely use `Handler`s on both `AsyncTask`s to communicate between them, even another one for the UI if you need to. You may find a good example [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html). For reference, look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).